# delete an element but keep contents in parent element in xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'm using xmlstarlet and want to convert elements of this sort:

```
<entry>
<para>Text</para>
</entry>
<entry>
<para>
<emphasis role=bold>text</emphasis>
</para>
```

to:

```
<entry>Text</entry>
<entry><emphasis role=bold>text</emphasis></entry>
```

Is this possible in xmlstarlet?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u //para/.. -x 'para/node()' para.xml
```

Which means: repace contents of every `para` parent with the contents of the `para`. Requires version 1.4.0+

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I am going to write this down, but i also think this ought to be added to the samples?

Comment: Not working on my side, is the syntax different on macos ?

Comment: @maxagaz macOS uses bash shell I believe, so the syntax should be the same.